# Angular - (blur) event on <td> gets fired and updates value in adjacent cell

Tags: angular, html-table, onblur

I am using Angular 8, I created a 2 dimensional array (elements) and then dynamically generated an html table with 2 *ngFor loops.

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let el of elements, let row = index">
    <td *ngFor="let e of el, let col = index" [attr.r] = "row" [attr.c] = "col" contenteditable="true" (blur)="changed($event)">{{ e }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My table cell are editable "td" elements and I set the row and column numbers with custom attributes "r" and "c".

The values in the cells get updated correctly when I change a update a cell in my 2 dimensional array.

I then added "(blur)" event to detect changes in the "td". The event gets fired as expected, but I get a weird behavior when trying to update the value in the array based on the update.

My changed() function is the following:

```
  changed(event) {
    console.log(event);
    let td = (event['target']) as HTMLTableDataCellElement;
    console.log(td);
    const row = td.getAttribute('r');
    const col = td.getAttribute('c');
    console.log('r: ' + row);
    console.log('c: ' + col);
    console.log('value: ' + td.innerHTML);
    this.elements[row][col] = td.innerHTML;
    console.log('elements[1][1]: ' + this.elements[1][1]);
    console.log('elements[1][2] ' + this.elements[1][2]);
    console.log('elements[2][1]: ' + this.elements[2][1]);
  }
```

My table looks like the following

[image]

I then enter a value in Cell "A1" (so element [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Vgj.png) of my array) and then click on another cell (does not matter which one) to trigger the "onBlur()" event

In the function triggered by the event, I am writing back the inputted value to the array. The array in the background gets the correct values, but the value I entered gets copied to the next cell on the right.

[image]

I have added several console.log in "changed()" and I get some quite weird values.
[image]

When I print the "td" it shows c="2", but when I query the attribute on the next row I get c="1". 
The array in the back-end seems to be updated correctly as [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Vgj.png)][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Vgj.png)] = 1 and [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Vgj.png)][[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUU9g.png)] = 0

I noticed that the issue only happens the first time a cell is changed. If i change A1, B1 will have the same value. But If I change A1 again, the issue will not happen again.

i have recreated the issue in this stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ta82dv

I have also tried to use the "focusout" event, but i get the same behavior. If there is a better/easier way to achive the two-way data binding, please don't hesitate to point me in another direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's just Angular change detection mechanism that has no way to differentiate all the bindings. So you need to provide `trackBy` function:

```html
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let el of elements, let row = index">
    <td *ngFor="let e of el, let col = index; trackBy: trackByIndex(row, col)" [attr.r] = "row" [attr.c] = "col" contenteditable="true" (blur)="changed($event)">{{ e }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the function:

```js
export class AppComponent  {

  trackByIndex(row, col) {
    return () => `${row}:${col}`
  }

}
```

Here's a link to a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-maggnl

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed.

Comment: As strange as it is, this solved my issue.